# Basin of attraction comparative statics* using local energy functions?

Tags: measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, stability

Let $\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}=\boldsymbol{F}(\boldsymbol{x};p)$ be an autonomous dynamical system defined on $[a,b]^n$ ($-\infty<a<B<\infty)$; $p\in\mathbb{R}$ is some fixed parameter. Suppose that $\boldsymbol{s}$ is an [asymptotically stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability#Definition_for_continuous-time_systems) steady state for any choice of $p$; given $p$, let $B_p\subseteq [a,b]^n$ denote its [basin of attraction.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor#Basins_of_attraction)

My question relates to whether I can use a result from [Alberto and Chiang (2015, p. 198)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/stability-regions-of-nonlinear-dynamical-systems/522A4FACB373591173A78C710BF004D8) to characterize how the Lebesgue measure of $B_p$ varies with $p$. This result is stated below, but a definition is needed first.

**Definition:** $V:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is a *local energy function* (around $\boldsymbol{s}$) if $\exists W\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. 
$\quad 1.$ $W$ is open and contains $\boldsymbol{s}$ 
$\quad 2.$ $\frac{d}{dt} V (x(t)) \leq 0 \ \, \forall x(t)\in W$

$\quad 3.$ $\left\{t\geq 0: \frac{d}{dt}V(x(t))=0\right\}$ has zero Lebesgue measure $\forall x(t)\in W$ s.t. $\underbrace{F(x(t);p)\neq 0}_{\text{i.e. not a steady state.}}$

**Result:** [(Alberto and Chiang, 2015, p. 198)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/stability-regions-of-nonlinear-dynamical-systems/522A4FACB373591173A78C710BF004D8): Suppose there exists a $V$ and $W$ that satisfy the above definition. For each $d\in\mathbb{R}$, let $S_d$ be the connected component of $\{\boldsymbol{x}\in[a,b]^n:V(\boldsymbol{x})\leq d\}$. Then $S^*:=\max_d\{S_d:S_d\subseteq W\}$ is "the largest estimate of [$B_p$] one can obtain via ... $V(\cdot)$."

**Finally, my question:** Suppose that I can choose a $V$ and $W$ that satisfy the above definition for all $p$ in an $\varepsilon$-ball centered at some $p_0\in\mathbb{R}$. Say I then apply the above method for an arbitrarily chosen $p\in (p_0-\varepsilon,p_0+\varepsilon)$; denote the resultant set $S^*_p$. Letting $\mu_{_{\mathcal{L}}}$ denote the Lebesgue measure, suppose that I can take the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial p} \mu_{_{\mathcal{L}}} (S^*_p)$, and find that it is, say, positive at $p=p_0$. Does this imply that $\mu_{_{\mathcal{L}}}(B_p)$ is increasing in $p$ at $p=p_0$?

Since $S_p^*$ is a *subset* of $B_p$, one would naturally worry that increasing $p$ could cause $S_p^*$ to increase/decrease and for $B_p$ to do the opposite. Can this indeed happen here? Or is $S_p^*$ constructed in a way that precludes this?

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance to anyone who takes the time to consider my question.

---

$^*\!$ **Note:** I realized that "comparative statics" is not standard math terminology. TL;DR, economists basically mean "$\frac{\partial}{\partial\  \text{parameter}} \text{(thing in model)} $," but if you would like to know more here's the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative_statics#:%7E:text=In%20economics%2C%20comparative%20statics%20is,in%20some%20underlying%20exogenous%20parameter.)!